# How to confirm only html files exist in a given folder and if not then how to prompt the user to specify a folder with only html files within

Tags: python

I would like to create a python script that will do 3 things:

1) Take user input to navigate to a file directory

2) Confirm the file contents (a particular set of files need to be in the folder for the script to proceed)

3) Do a Find and Replace

The Code as of now:

```
import os, time
from os.path import walk

mydictionary = {"</i>":"</em>"}

for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(raw_input('Copy and Paste Course Directory Here: ')):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.html'):
            filepath = os.path.join(path,f)
            s = open(filepath).read()
            for k, v in mydictionary.iteritems(): terms for a dictionary file and replace
                s = s.replace(k, v)
            f = open(filepath, 'w')
            f.write(s)
            f.close()
```

Now i Have parts 1 and 3, I just need part 2.

for part 2 though I need to confirm that only html files exist in the directory the the user will specified otherwise the script will prompt the user to enter the correct folder directory (which will contain html files)

Thanks

Comment: the problem is to add some code to specify that only html files exist in the folder the users specifies, if there are text files then I don't want the script to just quit rather print a message to the user to print the correct directory with html files in it

Comment: OP, your title needs some work. Please don't describe the solution, you may be going at *the problem* in the wrong way. [Describe the problem](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms).

Comment: any helps on the title then ?

Comment: "Help building a simple find and replace". Once you've changed the title, why not sign up for an account on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, and consider migrating the question over there?

Comment: @Droogans: I dont want to get help for find and replaces, rather i want to know how to make if condition, else condition statement here.

Comment: Ok. Can you simplify this question so that the *root* of you if/else problems are occurring, as to make it easier for us to pinpoint the issue you're having? We could offer a solution to using if/else to control the flow of logic...but the (currently) only answer posted here is trying to help you with "check[ing] if all the files in the directory are html files", not if/else statements.

Comment: I would like to check if the folder specified by the user has html files or not, if it does then i will run my search and replace script, if not then i will prompt the user to specify the correct folder with html files in it

Comment: The code that I've posted in my question only asks the user to input the file directory and then runs the search and replace. But Before running the search and replace i want python to confirm that the file directory provided by the user has html files in it or not since I want the search and replace to be only run on html files. if the folder doesn't have html then I want python to prompt the user to give the file directory to the folder with html files and then run the find and replace

Comment: @Ahmed: The problem here isn't "how to make an if and else statement", but how to write the _condition_ used by the if statement. So your title should describe the condition you're trying to write. Maybe something like, "How do I determine whether all files in a directory end with .html?"

Comment: @ Abarnert: I am only 12, and an immigrant. The only thing I understand is math and python (somewhat) which means that I am horrible in English, If you would like to suggest a title then that will be great. Thanks again

Comment: @ Guyz who didn't like the previous title: check out the new title and tell me if it's ok or not.

Comment: The new title is much better. It doesn't need to flow like Shakespeare, it just has to get the actual problem across. But you're missing one important word: you want to confirm that _only_ HTML files exist in a given folder, or that _all_ of the files in the folder are HTML, or something like that.

Comment: Also, for future reference, you'll get better/quicker answers on SO if you can remove anything irrelevant. The copy-and-replace stuff isn't actually part of your question. If you replace those 6 lines with, say, `do_stuff(filepath)`, people will know that whatever `do_stuff` does, you've already solved that for yourself and don't need help with it. Then they can focus on what you _do_ need help with. See http://sscce.org for more on that.

Comment: @ abarnert: I'm kinda confused with what u mean, if u could suggest an edit then that will be more helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, here's your pseudocode:

```
Ask user for directory
If all files in that directory are .html files:
    Do the search-and-replace stuff on the files
Else:
    Warn and repeat from start
```

I don't think you actually want a recursive walk here, so first I'll write that with a flat listing:

```
while True:
    dir = raw_input('Copy and Paste Course Directory Here: ')
    files = os.listdir(dir)
    if all(file.endswith('.html') for file in files):
        # do the search and replace stuff
        break
    else:
        print 'Sorry, there are non-HTML files here. Try again.'
```

Except for having the translate the "repeat from start" into a `while True` loop with a `break`, this is almost a word-for-word translation from the English pseudocode.

If you *do* need the recursive walk through subdirectories, you probably don't want to write the `all` as a one-liner. It's not that hard to write "all members of the third member of any member of the `os.walk` result end with `'.html'`", but it will be hard to read. But if you turn that English description into something more understandable, you should be able to see how to turn it directly into code.

Comment: @ abarnert: thanks man I think u understood me well. Problem Solved